# how to send location from android to web server

Tags: java, php, android

[The location class](https://github.com/rafaykh90/Protecta/blob/master/src/com/fyp/protecta/GPSTracker.java).

so I have this code that gives the location of an android device and I want it to send the location after that to php web server when a button on php web application is pressed , how can I do that ??

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! I recommend you take the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
to know your way arround here (and earn your first badge also ;) ). Also to improve the chances of getting useful answers
please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and also how to create [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question is a bit broad, could you narrow it down?

Answer (score 0):

That's an example of how to pass two parameters to a php web code and get back a String return:

```
        URL url;
        String stringReturn;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.mydomanin.com/myphp.php?latitude=" + myLatitude + "?longitude=" + myLongitude); 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inRead = new InputStreamReader(in);

            stringReturn = IOUtils.toString(inRead);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
```